# How to open web application if it is hosted in non-ascii computername

Tags: asp.net

My computername is in non-ascii character like ÄÖßÜÄÖßÜ. I am opening the web application using the url http://localhost/test/login.aspx.
It opens with that url. But when i try to open with the url like [http://ÄÖßÜÄÖßÜ/processmanager/login.aspx](http://%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9F%C3%9C%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9F%C3%9C/processmanager/login.aspx), it is not opening the page. Any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert this non ascii domain name to IDNA punycode.

You can convert it here. http://mct.verisign-grs.com/
**For example the name  ÄÖßÜÄÖßÜ -> xn--ssss-koac7jd6ce**

So if you edit your **hosts** file, on **c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc** you type

```
127.0.0.1 xn--ssss-koac7jd6ce
127.0.0.1 www.xn--ssss-koac7jd6ce
127.0.0.1 www.xn--ssss-koac7jd6ce.com
```

Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your local hosts file in `systemdrive\system32\drivers\etc` and add this entry

```
127.0.0.1 uemlautnaeme.
```

allowing you to access your site using

```
http://uemlautnaeme/
```

instead of ümlautnäme.

Comment: In host file it is 127.0.0.1 localhost. Thts why it is opening the url http://localhost/test/login.asox. But I want to open the url with the computername and the computername is in non-ascii chars.